# Home page content filtered by current location in magento 2

Tags: magento2

Is there any possible to load home content based on current location in magento 2? for example deals, brands etc.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, you need to set current location in session and use that session in every filter collection in deals, brands, etc.

Comment: thanks for your reply. please see the site weedmaps.com exactly i need the same in magento 2